# React-Native Customized Marker Slows Down Application

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, google-maps, google-maps-markers

When I use customized marker, the system starts to get heavy after a few processes. But if I use it without customization, there is no problem. I share a screenshot of my Marker's code, why I may have encountered such a problem.

So it's okay if I use the default marker. But if I designed it myself it works very slowly.

Number of Markers: 50

Library: react-native-maps, react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome5

CLOSE:

`tracksViewChanges={false}` I solved the problem by adding Props to Marker

tracksViewChanges: Sets whether this marker should track view changes. It's recommended to turn it off whenever it's possible to improve custom marker performance.

```
renderListMarker = () => {
    let { markerList } = this.props;
    return (
        markerList.map((item, index) => {
            return (
                <Marker
                    onPress={() => { this.selectMarker(index) }}
                    key={item._id}
                    coordinate={{
                        latitude: item.location.coordinates[0],
                        longitude: item.location.coordinates[1],
                    }}
                >
                    <View style={{ flexDirection: 'column', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                        <View style={{ marginBottom: -18, flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                            <View style={{ marginEnd: 2 }}>
                                <FontAwesome5 name="parking" size={24} color={this.state.marker === index ? "#3879f0" : "#000000"} />
                            </View>
                            {
                                item.empty !== false ? <View style={{ padding: 2, borderRadius: 2, backgroundColor: item.empty > 0 ? '#00cc96' : '#e63946', }}>
                                    <Text style={{ color: '#ffffff', fontWeight: 'bold', fontSize: 12 }}>{item.empty}</Text>
                                </View> : null
                            }
                        </View>
                        <View style={{ justifyContent: 'center' }}>
                            <FontAwesome5 name="sort-down" size={30} color={this.state.marker === index ? "#3879f0" : "#000000"} />
                        </View>
                    </View>

                </Marker>
            )
        }
        )
    )
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QRZXW.png)

Comment: `tracksViewChanges={false}` I solved the problem by adding Props to Marker

tracksViewChanges: Sets whether this marker should track view changes. It's recommended to turn it off whenever it's possible to improve custom marker performance.